# Why was my question deleted after it was closed as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions

Recently, a question was marked as a duplicate and deleted afterwards by three people.

Here is the question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63438790/move-span-to-top-right-corner-of-button/63438833#63438833).

I want to know why this question was deleted. Can anybody help me or describe why? And how can I find the reason why the specific question was deleted?

**Note 1:** I found some question and answer on meta that states duplicates don't get deleted.

***EDIT***

**Note 2** This is not my question link or pic... I put as a example question link and pic, but I posted answer for this question .. my actual question was how can I find the reason why delete the specific question? That is it...

**END EDIT**

Here is a picture of question for those who cannot see it:

[image]

Comment: Delete votes have no reason attached to them, so all you can do is ask the people who cast said delete votes.

Comment: only people with 10k rep (and yourself) can see it

Comment: The link looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7ahd.png) for us low reputation users.

Comment: peoples name are included .. who deleted the question ... for the reason i don't want to put the pic... please better check the link ...

Comment: @noor It doesnt matter, the people's names are included, that doesn't matter. We can't see the answer bc it's deleted.

Comment: @Kevin B someone invest his time .. what about this ? actually  i try to delete my own question  and give alert that you can not delete when people invest time  and i invest my time for this question ... what do you want to say ?

Comment: @noor i personally see no value in the question existing. That you invested time in it doesn't change that opinion.

Comment: @Kevin Bno ..  I got also 3  upvote and also who gave my question's answer .. answer not worthy of my question

Comment: @noor Yes, people upvote correct answers all the time, regardless of whether or not it's content that will help the network.

Comment: What I find helps, is searching for similar problems in the archives. Then I check one  question at a time with mine. If I find two or more very similar questions, I look at the answers. If the answers solve my problem, I am a happy bunny! If the answers did not help me, I try to figure out why, and include that missing piece of information in my question. In my question, I will also include the links to two or more "duplicates" *and* explain why my question is different and/or superior to theirs. Takes time, I know.

Comment: *someone invest his time* --> sorry but you simply wrote a one-line answer. If the fix is pretty easy and you were able to find it in less than 5min then consider the fact that the question is 99% a duplicate one. Actually I have invested more time to close the question than what you did to answer it.

Comment: I am commenting because I downvoted. Many of the comments above already describe the reason. Your answer lacked enough value or differentiation to make it worth keeping. It does not indicate that you were wrong. Simply, there is no need for users to have to sift through "the sky is blue" type answers..

Comment: @noor - It’s not necessary to censor the user who voted to delete your questions.  Those with enough reputation can see that information.  If an incorrect decision was made, then providing that information to everyone, is an important step to determine if that’s the case.  In this case, voting to delete the question, was the problem action

Comment: @Temani Afif _i suggest you think about :_   why he (question owner) asked question and why he invested his time to ask this question.

Comment: and why should I do this? it doesnt matter *who* asked and why he did it. Only the question and its content matter. SO is content oriented not user oriented.

Answer (score 24):

The reason why your duplicate was deleted is because it had no value. Stack Overflow exists to be a repository of knowledge. It's a little bit like an encyclopedia.

Imagine if you see the same thing said five times in an encyclopedia. Wouldn't that be weird? Same thing here.

Three users with the [delete vote privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) voted to delete your question because it has been asked ***soo*** many times before.

Most duplicates aren't deleted because they only have one other duplicate. But your question has been asked a lot of times that it has no value. Therefore, three high rep users voted to delete it.

Comment: being one of the deleters (and the gold who closed the question), I will add that the answer gave no explanation and no details : *add a property* isn't the best answer in SO and in this particular case it's a well known and common fix discussed to death (I can add more duplicates even needed)

Comment: @TemaniAfif So it was kind of link only? I guess that also makes sense.

Comment: not a link only but a trivial fix well known in the CSS world. Imagine that in the Python world someone start learning today and got an well known error, asked a question and someone give an answer within 2 min (with only the fix and no details) --> I am pretty sure that it's a duplicate and that a quick google search would give the answer

Comment: @TemaniAfif I have seen such examples, for instance people asking "Why is my lambda not working when there are no kwargs?". Such questions I close as a duplicate and then request deletion in SOCVR.

Answer (score 6):

> Can anybody help me or describe why?

In general, only the people who voted to delete can say for sure why they voted that way, but as others have indicated they likely believed that it was not valuable to the site to keep it. While questions that have low numbers of duplicates (or where the duplicate is deemed by the community to be high quality) are likely to be preserved, questions that have been asked and answered many times are likely to be deleted.

Since questions that are marked as duplicates can't be answered, their main value to the site is to point people to the correct answer. If there are already lots of these signposts, then there's little value to adding one more.

[image]

If the above photo seems a little excessive to you, it's an illustration of why we remove duplicates that have been asked many times before - at some point, it's simply not helpful.

> And how can I find the reason for why it was deleted.

Unless someone commented explaining why they voted the way they did, you can't.

> I found some question and answer on meta that states duplicates don't get deleted.

You're probably referring to auto-deletion (the Roomba). The rules for this are a little complicated, but duplicates follow the same rules for auto-deletion as non-closed questions. The mere fact that a question is marked as a duplicate does not influence when, or whether, a question will Roomba. Being marked as a duplicate *does* allow users with enough reputation to vote to delete the question manually, though.

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, the reasons are self evident.  Closed duplicate questions get deleted because they and their answers have been deemed to provide no *ongoing* value; i.e they won't help future readers.

> Note: I found some question and answer on meta that states duplicates don't get deleted.

Duplicates don't get deleted *automatically* because sometimes the answers on a duplicate answer are useful ... and automation cannot make that call.  (Unfortunately, this leads to lots of low-value duplicates not being deleted, duplicate chains / trees, and other things.  However curating duplicates is something that requires full moderator privileges AND subject knowledge.  So the curation rarely happens.  I observe.)

In this case, 3 people made the call that there was no value in keeping yet another duplicate and its answer.

But here's the thing, it was probably not a good idea for you to answer that question in the first place.  It is best to search for existing questions yourself *before* you spend time on writing an answer.  Better you, and better for the site:

- The site is benefited because there future readers are less likely to land on the "low value" page.
- You are benefited because you don't spend time writing an answer that is *unlikely* to get you upvotes and reputation.  (And if you don't care about that, then it shouldn't worry you that the Q&A got deleted.)